# How to debug the MongoDB error "order.addresses.setup is undefined"?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, shell, mongodb-query, robo3t

```
db.getCollection('order').find({bundleProducts:{$elemMatch:{id:"5720a0ce7709"}}}).forEach(
function(order){ print(
    "invoice addresses: " + order.addresses.invoice.city + "," +
    " delivery addresses: "+ order.addresses.delivery.city+","+
    " setup addresses: "+ order.addresses.setup.city+","); }) ;
```

when I run the above question

Failed to execute script.

```
Error:
TypeError: order.addresses.setup is undefined :
@(shell):5:1
DBQuery.prototype.forEach@src/mongo/shell/query.js:501:1
@(shell):1:1
```

I'm getting an error.
How can I write a query if the installation address is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to access an non existing field (`setup`) that's why you are getting error, You may want to use [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator if you want to exclude documents that do not contain the `setup` field, here is an example:

```
db.getCollection('order').find({
    bundleProducts: {
        $elemMatch: { id: "5720a0ce7709" }
    },
    "addresses.setup": { $exists: true }
}).forEach( function(order){ print(
    "invoice addresses: " + order.addresses.invoice.city + "," +
    " delivery addresses: " + order.addresses.delivery.city + ","+
    " setup addresses: " + order.addresses.setup.city + ","); 
});
```

Comment: thank you so much :)),
I was experimenting with the if else operator.

The $exist operator is better..
Thank you :)